# How to get the value of an input box without an id using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm using jQuery 1.11x and I have two text fields that the user can select dates with (not a jquery datepicker, but a custom js calendar that has lots of code in it) and both textboxes have their own id's, like date1 and date2.  However, either can be selected, but not both and I'm trying to dynamically determine the value of the date selected in the textbox.

For example, if I knew the id, I could use:

```
var date = new Date($(#date1).val());
```

to get the value, but I don't know which one the user selected.  There is an onclick event that fires off the custom js calendar code and it passes the element like this:

```
onClick="setDateField(document.Form1.date1); etc... opens a new window for the calendar
```

which sets the textbox with a string date from the value the user selected.  When the user clicks my submit button I have a validate function that I need to get the date value from, but I'm not sure which textbox was used?

Something like:

```
onclick="javascript:validate(document.Form1.date1,1);" or
onclick="javascript:validate(document.Form1.date2,1);"
```

On the above line ",1" is just a display format param for the calendar.

The problem with all this is that it is very old jsp code and I have to use scriptlets to display the date1 or date2 textboxes, depending on if I am retrieving data to display or allowing new user input.

So is there a way to dynamically get the value of the textbox without knowing it's id?

Comment: Yes there is, although you will need to know where it is in the DOM. For example: knowing that the text box is the second child of the `<form>`, has a certain `class`, etc.

Comment: Will it be one textbox or the other? or could there be a case in which both will be populated?

Comment: Only one textbox will be displayed at a time.  It won't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could detect the last clicked input id like this:

```
$('input[id^=date]').on('focus', function() {
    var lastUsedDateInputId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Or get the last input value like this:

```
$('input[id^=date]').on('blur', function() {
    var lastUsedDateInputValue = $(this).val();
});
```